# How to extract substring in C

Tags: c, file, substring

I am reading the data from a file and I need to extract only integers from the below data.How do I accomplish it? Thanks.

My input will be field6 and I need to remove these characters "];" and store it in an integer variable.

My code:-

```
field6 = strtok(NULL," ");
if (isdigit(field6))
{
   weight = atoi (field6);
   printf("%d\n",weight);
}
```

Input:

```
43];
2];
4];
16];
25];
```

Output:

```
43
2
4
16
25
```

Comment: Google `isdigit()` and `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: Perfect task for one of the scanf functions.

Comment: @H2CO3 But my input is a string.

Comment: @SOaddict But you can make it a character by dereferencing it... you know, pointers :)

Comment: @SOaddict Then explain more cause you said a file @_@

Comment: @H2CO3 Parsing it char by char is a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: @Troy You want to say you trust `scanf()`?

Comment: @H2CO3 For something as simple as that, for sure.

Comment: @Troy *"Parsing it char by char is a lot of unnecessary work"* Depends on what behavior you want on incorrect input. The `scanf` family of functions provide very limited error management choices, not to mention idiosyncratic behavior in some cases. They are always tempting but not always a good idea.

Comment: @dmckee Yes, that's what I mean :)

Comment: Does anyone have solution for me..?

Comment: Do you have to use C? There exist time tested things like regex that are much better for parsing. Languages like perl, python, java, boost & c++. Do this much better.

Comment: What is the expected behavior in the case that the first character is not a digit?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without sscanf then:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  const char *test = "123];";

  int i = 0;

  const char *p = test;
  while (*p && isdigit(*p))
  {
    if (p != test) i *= 10;
    i += *p - '0';
    ++p;
  }

  if (*p != ']')
  {
    // we have an error!
    return 1;
  }

  printf("%i\n", i);
}
```

Comment: +1 for _almost_ not even needing libc ... isdigit could be `*p>='0' && *p<='9'` ... not counting printf as that is just for demo

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
field6 = strtok(NULL,"\n");
weight = atoi (field6);
printf("%d\n",weight);
```

This is one of those rare conditions where atoi does exactly what you need it to do.

The error condition that would be undetected is "];"  That would be interpreted as zero.